# How to create a JSON array in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I want to create a JSON array like this:

```
var ddBasic = [
    { text: "Facebook", value: 1, },
    { text: "Twitter", value: 2, },
    { text: "LinkedIn", value: 3, },
    { text: "Foursquare", value: 4, }
];
```

I'm using data from last.fm, so it would be something like this:

```
var tags = [
        { text: "rock", value: "rock", },
        { text: "pop", value: "pop", },
    ];
```

It needs to have a comma at the end so the [ddslick](http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick#demo) dropdown function ignores the imageSrc and other things it can use for a dropdown, other it throws this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'imageSrc' of undefined
```

To tie everything together, I have:

```
$('#tag').ddslick({
    data: tags,
    onSelected: function(selectedData) {}   
});
```

This is the function that gets the tags:

```
var tags = [];

var getTopTracks = function () {
    $.getJSON(
    settings.PHP_REQUEST_URL, {
        method: "tag.getTopTags",
        api_key: settings.LASTFM_APIKEY,
        format: "json",
    },

    function (data) {
        var limit = 50;

        data.toptags.tag.sort(function (t1, t2) {
            return t2.count - t1.count;
        });

        $.each(data.toptags.tag, function (i, item) {
            if (i > limit) return false;
            console.log(item.name);
            tags.push({
                text: item.name,
                value: item.name
            });
        });
    });
};

// event handlers (load quando o form é invocado só)
getTopTracks();
alert(tags.length);

// define tema para a combobox   
$('#tag').ddslick({
    data: tags,
    onSelected: function (selectedData) {}
});
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You're saying it works fine with the comma? I don't see how that would make a difference.

Comment: Oh...apparently it wasn't the comma, it's something in my array. I'm pushing values with `tags.push({"text" : item.name, "value" : item.name});` - is this the correct syntax? Length shows 0 after pushing, which makes me wonder what's wrong.

Comment: Check the console for errors... is `item` defined?

Comment: Yes, if I do `console.log(item.name);` in the `$.each` loop it prints out all the tags.

Comment: I can't tell you what's wrong with your code unless you update your question with your code.

Comment: You have an extra `});` at the end. (I took it out but make sure its not in your actual code)

Comment: Could be a scope issue. do console.log on tags right after you call push.

Comment: @sachleen: possible but this would mean there's another `tags` variable hiding somehwere (well: where?) because otherwise `push` would throw something like `can not call push on undefined`

Comment: Fixed, it was because I was trying to get values before AJAX finished the request. All fixed. Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var tags = []; //initialised tags with length 0
getTopTracks(); //fetching date in background (!)
alert(tags.length); //running while data is still fitched (unless you've a 0ping connection => alerting length 0
```

At the point you use the alert it's very likely `tags` is not filled as `$.getJSON()` is an *asynchronus* request, meaning the request will be handled in the background and execution of the script continues. You have to use the callback method as you already did for filling up the array.

```
This, getJSON, is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to:
$.ajax({   
   url: url,
   dataType: 'json',
   data: data,
   success: callback
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

```
//getJSON success callback:
function (data) {
    var limit = 50;

    data.toptags.tag.sort(function (t1, t2) {
        return t2.count - t1.count;
    });

    $.each(data.toptags.tag, function (i, item) {
        if (i > limit) return false;
        console.log(item.name);
        tags.push({
            text: item.name,
            value: item.name
        });
    });
    //alert the length AFTER the tags been pushed
    alert(tags.length);

    // define tema para a combobox   
    $('#tag').ddslick({
        data: tags,
        onSelected: function (selectedData) {}
    });
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, it's because I'm doing this on page load, which means that it loads the elements before the call is made. How do I wait until it finishes?

Comment: You move your code after the `$.each` into the callback method. So you make sure it's get executed after the array was filled.

Comment: value is okay but text property showing as undefined:

Comment: @Can Ürek: uhm can't really follow. Would you mind writing another question for your problem possible with a minimal example?

Comment: I handle that. My solution like that. var json = {}; json[name] = value; That's work for me.

Comment: Glad to hear you've fixed it \^.^/